# Is there any OLAP Library for SQLite in .Net?

Tags: .net, sqlite, olap, olap-cube

I would like to know is there any OLAP libray for SQLite? which will allow me to create CUBES dynamically.

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: SQLite is not designed to be an OLAP database it is an OLTP database.